# Magento - how to write in the admin actions log?

Tags: php, logging, admin, magento

As per title. Can't seem to find anything relevant.

Comment: Are you talking about the logging feature that only comes with Enterprise edition?

Comment: Yep. I have tried to trace back a couple of the actions that do appear in the log, i.e. invoice/view, but with no success. I don't seem to find (or recognize) the bit that does the logging.

Answer (score 1):

app/code/core/Enterprise/Logging is what I think your looking for.

This is from the Model/Handler/Controllers.php file.

```
    //Add log entry details
    if ($data) {
        $change = Mage::getModel('enterprise_logging/event_changes');
        $processor->addEventChanges($change->setSourceName('params')
            ->setOriginalData(array())
            ->setResultData($data));
    }
```

I've never used it but hope it helps?